# InfoPath 2010 Error: InfoPath cannot start Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications. InfoPath has encountered the Error. The operation failed

Tags: sharepoint, infopath2010, vsta

Everything was working fine. I have windows8.1, VS 2010, VS 2013 installed on the same machine.Ms office 2013 was installed without infopath and InfoPath 2010 was installed already with MS Sharepoint 2010 and it was working fine with code behind. Suddenly mistakingly someone updated to MS Office 2016 and now I have tried installing Ms Infopath 2010 again it installs properly but when i click on code on MS Infopath 2010. it gives error "InfoPath cannot start Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications. InfoPath has encountered the Error. The operation failed.". I have installed  msxml6.msi.  I have checked everything installed VSTA too. tried every solution but my code behind is not opening VSTA. I installed  msxml6.msi too. but one thing I noticed if I run VSTA from my command it opens up but its not opening with infopath. I have lost hope. What could be the reason. Please help. I ll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

After several failed attempts, I installed visual studio tools for office system 3.0 and luckily it worked. :)